# Why paypal required cards to process payments for some and not for all websites?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, e-commerce

I just want to ask, I'm using wordpress, s2member plugin and I can't successfully process the payment for my subscriptions since I need first a card for my Paypal account (unverified) to pay (testing purposes).
However, using the same paypal account I have already purchased some items online, on  a wordpress website (e-commerce). Why is this happening? Can I avoid or do something that can process the subscriptions (just like the other website I mentioned) to purchase online using unverified Paypal accounts?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscriptions require a credit card. 
Other websites might have a simple checkout (As opposed to subscription), which can be paid for using PayPal balance( ie, no CC required).

By the way, make sure you use a completely separate account for testing. You can't make a payment to yourself :)